# gmapping without robot_pose_ekf

Tags: slam, navigation, robot-pose-ekf, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I tried running pr2 in gazebo (pr2.launch), but removing the robot_pose_ekf in "pr2_bringup.launch" plus setting the parameter "odom_frame" to "odom" (changing from odom_combined to odom) for slam_gmapping node. Also, to get the tfs from odometry I changed "publish_tf" to true in pr2_odometry.yaml (in /pr2_simulator/pr2_controller_configuration_gazebo/pr2_odometry.yaml). Actually I am changing a custom launch files not the originals.

When I visualize it in rviz, using both the fixed frame and target frame set to /odom I see the pr2 is kind of blinking (Robot Model status changing back and forth between OK and Error).

Also, in the Map field I get a status error saying that "No transform from [map] to [/odom]". Thus, the map is not aligned in the display.

What is happening here? By the way I am running ros-electric in ubuntu 11.04.

Thank you in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37331/gmapping-without-robot_pose_ekf/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are seeing is a TF problem. I could replicate your error, and `roswtf` shows:

```
ERROR TF re-parenting contention:
 * reparenting of [/odom] to [/map] by [/slam_gmapping]
 * reparenting of [/odom] to [/base_footprint] by [/gazebo]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/slam_gmapping] publishing transform [/odom] with parent [/map] already published by node [/gazebo]
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [/odom] with parent [/base_footprint] already published by node [/slam_gmapping]
```

What this means is that `slam_gmapping` publishes the TF frame `/map` as parent of `/odom`, but the PR2 controllers (which show up as `/gazebo`) also publish `/odom`, but this time with `/base_footprint` as its parent. The trouble is that a TF frame can only have exactly one parent.

When running with `robot_pose_ekf` enabled (before your changes), the TF tree looks like this:

```
map ------> odom_combined ------> base_footprint
```

The first transform is published by gmapping, the second by `robot_pose_ekf`.

Now, your TF tree looks like this:

```
           map ---
                   \
                     ---> odom
                   /
base_footprint ---
```

... which is illegal. I think the reason why odom is published as a child of `base_footprint` instead of a parent is so that you can have `odom` and `odom_combined` both published at the same time.

The solution would be that somehow you need to make `odom` a parent of `base_footprint`. For example, you could switch `publish_tf` back off, write a small node that listens to the `odom` **topic** (not TF transform) and publishes that as a TF transform from `odom` to `base_footprint`.

Just for curiosity's sake: why do you want to remove `robot_pose_ekf`?

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-26**:
@Martin Günther Thank you very much for the wonderful explanation.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-26**:
@Martin Günther Well, I am working on a rover navigating on 3D terrain. And, after going through the robot_pose_ekf code I realized it cannot be used straightaway for inclined planes (http://answers.ros.org/question/32183/robot_pose_ekf-on-an-inclined-plane/). So i just unplugged it.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-26**:
@Martin Günther gmapping cannot be used for 3D as well; that I am aware of by the way :)